# Default Style for token - webform_submission:values

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm wondering if there is a way to theme the default style for the webform token `[webform_submission:values]`.

The emails being sent with no space between the label and the value.
So they look like this: 
`Example LableExample Value`

I just want to add a semicolon and a space after the label.
Is that possible without having to use a custom body for every webform?
Like this:
`Name: [submission:values:name:nolabel]`

Comment: FYI, I'm using webform 5.0 and Drupal 8.6.2.

Comment: Are you sending HTML emails or plain text?  HTML emails should be formatted with bold labels and breaks.  Plain text should have colons and returns. @see webform-element-base-text.html.twig and webform-element-base-html.html.twig.  It is possible that your email sender is stripping HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks. I've verified that that is indeed the file being used, no other template is overriding it, so there must be something else stripping tags. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I appreciate it.

Comment: I found what is stripping tags. There is a custom module that runs the message body through Xss::filter(), like this -> $body = Xss::filter($body). Do you think I'm safe to remove this filter?

Comment: For email messages, you generally don't need to filter the content. To be safe you might want to use Xss::filterAdmin($body).  The specific issue here is the default HTML tags for Xss::filter are don't include <b> or <br/>. @see \Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::$htmlTags